# Chrome fadeIn scroll bar issue

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, scrollbar, fadein

[Bikram Website](http://www.bikramyogascarboroughbeach.com.au/instructors/instructors.html)

If you view this page in the latest version of chrome you will notice when you click on an instructors name the scroll bar is black when fading in. It is not a webkit issue as safari is fine. Anybody know why chrome does it?

Comment: I do not see the bar as black.  Can you check  your version of chrome?  Mine is version 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the same behavior in Chrome 5.0.375.55.  I would suggest setting the css overflow-y of your '.scroller' divs to 'hidden' until after the fade in and then set it to 'auto'.

Comment: Cheers mate, I will give it a go! Sorry Jonathon I forgot to mention it was a XP problem only... seems ok in win7 and mac

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in chrome:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20169

It seems to affect Chrome in Windows when there is no desktop compositor (when not using Aero).

It's been there for a LONG time.